Python - tkinter - Button - wrong command - what is wrong?
I'm creating a game called NIM in Python
stack = heap
This was my previous code with fixed amount of stacks (heaps) and everything is working fine
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pack_kwargs = {'fill' : BOTH, 'expand' : True, 'padx' : ['0', '0'], 'pady' : ['0', '0']}

    def player1(self):
        def chooseStack(stack):
            self.stack = stack
            window_player1_stack.destroy()

        btn1 = Button(window_player1_stack, text = '1', bd = '2', command = lambda: chooseStack(0))  
        btn2 = Button(window_player1_stack, text = '2', bd = '2', command = lambda: chooseStack(1))  
        btn3 = Button(window_player1_stack, text = '3', bd = '2', command = lambda: chooseStack(2))

        if self.stacks[0]: btn1.pack(**self.pack_kwargs)
        if self.stacks[1]: btn2.pack(**self.pack_kwargs)
        if self.stacks[2]: btn3.pack(**self.pack_kwargs)

but I want to make it possible play with any amount of stacks (instead of fixed), and it doesn't work - it always chooses last stack, not the one I've chosen
for i in range(len(self.stacks)):
    Button(window_player1_stack, text = f'{i+1}', bd = '2', command = lambda: chooseStack(i)).pack(**self.pack_kwargs)

Stack chosing
Chosing amount of stones to take
I tried doing like this and still didn't work
buttons = []
for i in range(len(self.stacks)):
    button = Button(window_player1_stack, text = f'{i+1}', bd = '2', command = lambda: chooseStack(i))
    buttons.append(button)

if self.stacks[0]: buttons[0].pack(**self.pack_kwargs)
if self.stacks[1]: buttons[1].pack(**self.pack_kwargs)
if self.stacks[2]: buttons[2].pack(**self.pack_kwargs)

I'm sorry if my english is not very good

you have wrong indentation - you should run if self.stacks ... after for-loop, not inside loop.

what means doesn't work ?  We can't run code, we can't see your computer, and we can't read in your mind. You have to describe all details in question (not in comments)

you have common problem with lambda in loop. It doesn't send value from i to lambda but only reference to variable i and it gets value from i when you press button but at this moment variable i has last value from for-loop - so all buttons get the same value from i. You have to use lambda x=i: chooseStack(x)...

It seems you have common problem with lambda in loop.
It doesn't send value from i to lambda but only reference to variable i
and it gets value from i when you press button
but at this moment variable i has last value from for-loop - so all buttons get the same value from i.
You have to use lambda x=i: chooseStack(x)... to copy value to another variable.
for i in range(len(self.stacks)):
    button = Button(window_player1_stack, text=f'{i+1}', bd='2', 
                      command=lambda x=i: chooseStack(x))
    buttons.append(button)

